# Delphi - проверка RadioButton'ов на True

Tags: delphi

Пишу ПО для тестирования специалистов (проверка знаний).
Есть группа `RadioButton`'ов (3-10 элементов).
Проверяю так:

```
procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
 if RadioButton1.Checked=false and RadioButton2.Checked=false and ... RadioButton[N].Checked=false then
   begin
     Showmessage ('Для продолжения выберите ответ.');
   end
 else
   begin
     if i<=[N] then
       begin
         i:=i+1;
         (* тут покажем пользователю вопросы.
         и почистим RadioButton'ы *)
         RadioButton1.Checked:=false;
         ....
         RadioButton[N].Checked:=false;
       end;
   end;
end;
```

Заминка у меня в том, что при создании формы, RadioButton'ам уже выставляется `Unchecked`. Дабы первый открывшийся тест был без установленного в `Checked` `RadioButton`'а. И происходит, естественно, что при первом нажатии кнопки Button2, срабатывает событие `Showmessage`.
Как это обойти?

Т.е. Что-бы первое нажатие кнопки не брало значение `RadioButton`'ов.
Выход писать какой-то индекс на то, что нажатие является первым?
Или есть что-то более универсальное и более традиционное?

**Дополнение:**
Делаю трассировку, ставлю Check на любой RadioButton, но условие

```
if (RadioButton1.Checked=false and RadioButton2.Checked=false and RadioButton3.Checked=false) then
  begin
    Showmessage ('Для продолжения выбирите ответ.');
  end;
```

всё равно  срабатывает.
(что-то я всё позабыл за 10 лет.)

Comment: Уточните, при открытии формы все метки сняты, если нажать кнопку, то возникает сообщение? А как должно быть?

Comment: @KromStern, Возникает - "Для продолжения выберите ответ.". Так должно же быть не выбрал, не идёшь вперёд.

Comment: А какое поведение вы ожидаете? Хоть при первом, хоть при сотом нажатии, если пользователь не отметил ни один ответ, вам же нужно показать ему этот `Showmessage` в любом случае.

Comment: @zed тут-то я и понимаю. Но вот трассеровка показала ещё вот какую штуку: Ставлю check на какой-нибудь RadioButton, дохожу до `if (RadioButton1.Checked=false and RadioButton2.Checked=false and RadioButton3.Checked=false) then
  begin
    Showmessage ('Для продолжения выбирите ответ.');
  end;` но трассеровка показывает, что событие сработает. Но он же выбран. Почему вдруг условие срабатывает?

Comment: В Делфе такой код не может быть откомпилирован: `if (RadioButton1.Checked=false and RadioButton2.Checked=false and RadioButton3.Checked=false) then`. Приведите пример с настоящим/работающим кодом.

Comment: В `if` сравнивать с `True` или `False` это моветон. Делайте так: `if not RadioButton1.Checked and not RadioButton2.Checked and ... then ...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Меняйте тэг кнопки, например:

```
if (Button2.Tag == 0) then // если нажатие произошло в первый раз
    begin
        Button2.Tag := 1;
        Exit;
    end;
else
    // ваши действия
```

только непонятно какой в этом смысл.

P.S.: `бер / бир` корни с чередованием.

Comment: @ Спасибо! Реализовал пока на данном этапе через тэг. Так же как и сам думал, но я применяю обычно простой индекс. Хотя функционально разницы ни какой нет.

Answer (score 3):

Данную проблему лучше решать при помощи стандартного компонента `RadioGroup`.

Это уже готовая группа `RadioButton`'ов с необходимым функционалом. Если ни один элемент не выбран, свойство `ItemIndex` будет равно `-1`, иначе оно будет равно индексу выбранного `RadioButton`'а (индексация начинается с `0`).

Простейший пример:

```
if RadioGroup1.ItemIndex = -1 then
    ShowMessage('Выберите вариант!')
else
    ShowMessage('Выбран вариант - ' + RadioGroup1.Items[RadioGroup1.ItemIndex]);
```

Comment: Ни чего не понимаю, но трассеровка после установки Check на RadioButton всё равно показывает "-1" у RadioGroup1.ItemIndex.

Comment: @I_CaR, вероятно данный `RadioButton` просто не относится к `RadioGroup`, а существует сам по себе, "живя своей жизнью". Судя по коду, который Вы поместили в дополнении к вопросу, скорее всего, так оно и есть. Переделайте отдельные `RadioButton`'ы в `Item`'ы `RadioGroup`.

Comment: я уже понял эту ситуацию, но пока не созрел переписывать уже кучу кода. Пошёл по ветке с индексом кнопки. slippyk тоже указал метод очень схожий с индексом на кнопку (менять тег).

Comment: Здесь уже Вам решать.

Answer (score 1):

Я в своей практике исключал действия дурного пользователя на корню. Если он не должен идти до тех пока не выберет один из вариантов, заблокируй кнопку продолжения.

```
OnFormShow(sender:tobject);
Begin
..
NextStepBtn.enabled:=false;
..
End;

//Повесить обработчик на все radiobutton
OnRadioButtonAnyClick(sender:tobject);
Begin
..
//Чтобы все radiobutton не перебирать проверяем что хотя бы одна checked 
if ( sender as tradiobutton).checked then
 NextStepBtn.enabled:=true
Else //мы не знаем состояние других поэтому если хотя одна checked, будет доступен следующий шаг.
// Если все будут unchecked следующий шаг недоступен
nextstepbutton.enabled:=((radiobutton1.checked) or (radiobutton2.checked) .. or (radiobutton[N].checked));
..
End;

OnNextStepButtonClick(sender:tobject);
Begin
..
//Переход к следующему шагу
NextStepBtn.enabled:=false;
End;
```